# Class wizard from dialog box in VC ++ 9.0

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

Does anybody know how to bring a class wizard from a dialog box in MFC application using VC++ 9.0 only.

Answer (score 1):

The file for class wizard has .clw extension. It resides to the rest of the files of the projects you work. You can just add it to another project though I am not sure for the actual use.